# Pass arbitrary connection options to Farday

Tags: ruby, faraday

I'm trying to convert a project I have from using `Excon` to `Faraday` with the `Excon` adapter, but I'm not having any luck.

The issue is that I need to pass through some arbitrary connection options to `Excon` as the API I am interfacing with uses client side SSL certs for authentication.

To make the connection with straight `Excon` I was using this:

```
@connection = Excon.new("some_url", client_cert: File.expand_path(@some_cert), client_key: File.expand_path(@some_key))
```

According to the Faraday documention, I should be able to do something like this:s

```
@connection = Faraday::Connection.new(url: "some_url", client_cert: File.expand_path(@some_cert), client_key: File.expand_path(@some_key)) do |faraday|
  faraday.adapter :excon
end
```

When I try that (with the 0.9 RC5 from Github), I get an `undefined method client_cert=` error, which leads me to believe the documentation is out of date.  Does anybody know how to pass arbitrary connection options through to an adapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the SSL options as a hash.  This should work:

```
ssl_opts = {
  client_cert: File.expand_path(@some_cert),
  client_key: File.expand_path(@some_key)
}
@connection = Faraday::Connection.new(url: "some_url", ssl: ssl_opts) do |faraday|
  faraday.adapter :excon
end
```

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/mislav/938183) has some more examples for using SSL with Faraday.

Comment: unfortunately, that still does not work.  the ssl options do not get passed through to the excon adapter. basically it doesn't matter what i put in, nothing makes it into the connection_options here: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday/adapter/excon.rb#L6   Seems like this could possibly be a bug in Faraday...

Comment: This was actually a bug in Faraday, but I made a pull request that would implement this as described.  So while it is not the correct answer at this present time, it should be before too long.